# What is a cross-platform way to clear and reuse a Rust PathBuf?

Tags: rust

In an effort to keep overhead as low as possible when processing a large number of filesystem paths, I want to avoid allocating memory for each path. Is there a way to clear and reuse a `PathBuf`?

From what I could find in the docs, reusing a `PathBuf` is possible when dealing with absolute paths via a `PathBuf::push` (at least on POSIX systems), but I haven't found a way to reuse a `PathBuf` when dealing with a relative path.

Is there a way to do this in a cross-platform manner or am I forced to process these paths in a platform specific way?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that something like `path = "./local".into()` is optimized to not do additional allocation. BTW, trying to focus on some micro-optimizations like that does not worth it, IMHO.

Comment: Oh, looks like I'm wrong: in release mode, this still compiles to `callq std::ffi::os_str::OsStr::to_os_string` that does a new allocation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way is to convert the `PathBuf` to its internal storage, clear that, and convert it back to the `PathBuf`. This requires no extra allocation:

```
use std::path::PathBuf;

fn main() {
    let path = PathBuf::from("../tmp");
    let mut path = path.into_os_string();
    path.clear();
    let mut path = PathBuf::from(path);
    path.push("../etc");
    assert_eq!(path, PathBuf::from("../etc"));
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5219c2844d339e4e63251e5473418a9b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

Comment: I just checked `PathBuf`'s implementation of `From<OsString>`, and it does indeed not allocate any memory (surprisingly it doesn't even validate the string). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: There isn't much to validate. On Linux the only character not allowed in a path is NUL, but the `OsString` must be NUL-terminated, so the first NUL is interpreted as the end of the path. As for `/`, any sequence is allowed, and duplicate are removed `///foo//bar////` is valid and the same as `/foo/bar/` (the only exception is two leading slashes are implementation defined for POSIX, but I don't know any system that still use those differently).